# How to make new environment using an existing environment? File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine

Tags: environments, verbatim, fancyvrb

I have a setup that works OK as is. I needed to make this code as an environment so less typing. When I do that I get an error.

Here is the original setup

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb,xcolor}
\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners,boxrule=.1pt,colframe=red!75!black,boxsep=2pt]%
\begin{Verbatim}
 some code here
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The above compile with no error. Now I did the following

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb,xcolor}
\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{TEXTinline}%
{%
 \begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners,boxrule=.1pt,colframe=red!75!black,boxsep=2pt]%
 \begin{Verbatim}
}%
{%
 \end{Verbatim}
 \end{tcolorbox}%
}%
\begin{document} 
    
\begin{TEXTinline}
some code here
\end{TEXTinline}
\end{document}
```

And now lualatex main.tex gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> main.tex
```

I think this is related to Verbatim only. So I tried to define Verbatim environment calling in `X400`, but that also did not work

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb,xcolor}
\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{X400}{Verbatim}{frame=single,framerule=0.8pt,framesep=2mm}

\newenvironment{TEXTinline}%
{%
 \begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners,boxrule=.1pt,colframe=red!75!black,boxsep=2pt]%
 \begin{X400}
}%
{%
 \end{X400}
 \end{tcolorbox}%
}%
\fi 
\begin{document} 


\begin{TEXTinline}
some code here
\end{TEXTinline}

\end{document}
```

Same error.

I sort of remember such an issue using Verbatim inside new environment, because Verbatim wants to be in place only? but now do not and can't find a resolution to this.

Is it possible to define the above new environment and have Verbatim environment inside it?

TL 2023

Comment: in general you can not nest verbatim, as inside verbatim commands are disabled so your `\end{TEXTinline}` is just a string and does not end any environment. But tcolorbox provides facilities for defining boxed verbatim environments, check its manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\VerbatimEnvironment`. Not really well documented…

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb,xcolor}
\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{TEXTinline}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners,boxrule=.1pt,colframe=red!75!black,boxsep=2pt]%
  \begin{Verbatim}%
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{TEXTinline}
some code here
\end{TEXTinline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know of similar trick that will work for `\begin{verbatim}`  and not just `\begin{Verbatim}`  ? sometimes I prefer `verbatim` over `Verbatim` for tex4ht issue. But `\VerbatimEnvironment` does not work with `verbatim` only `Verbatim`. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser You can do `\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{}`, so `verbatim` is the same as `Verbatim`.